# How can I create a list of points (two dimensional arrays) in python using two lists of random variables

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I try to train a Perceptron using some random data. It seems my data doesn't match the format of inputs for the Perceptron class:

Here is the way I tray to create my data:

```
Q1 = 100
X1 = 1 + 0.5*np.random.randn(Q1,1)
X2 = 1 + 0.5*np.random.randn(Q1,1)


my_training_inputs = np.array(list(zip(X1, X2)))
my_labels = np.ones((len(X1),))
```

Here is the format I must prepare my data above:

```
training_inputs = []
training_inputs.append(np.array([1, 1]))
training_inputs.append(np.array([1, 0]))
training_inputs.append(np.array([0, 1]))
training_inputs.append(np.array([0, 0]))

labels = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0])
```

How can I prepare my data in this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.concatenate`:

```
Q1 = 100
X1 = 1 + 0.5*np.random.randn(Q1,1)
X2 = 1 + 0.5*np.random.randn(Q1,1)

my_training_inputs = np.concatenate((X1,X2), axis=1)
my_labels = np.ones((len(X1),))   

print(my_labels.shape)
#(100,)

print(my_training_inputs.shape)
#(100, 2)

#print the 4 first samples (inputs)
print(my_training_inputs[0:4])
#array([[0.754558  , 0.76998302],
#       [0.0716354 , 1.34796436],
#       [1.25007314, 1.61079584],
#       [0.74931903, 0.9899375 ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You must not add brackets in the definition of `X1` and `X2`, because `np.random.randn(Q1,1)` already is an array. Simply replace the definition of `X1` and `X2` by this:

```
X1 = 1 + 0.5*np.random.randn(Q1,1)
X2 = 1 + 0.5*np.random.randn(Q1,1)
```

Comment: thanks, I removed them from my code and from the question, but it doesn't help me yet.